# Fonts goes bigger in high resolution device

Tags: android, screen-size, android-resolution

In my App, I set font sizes and run my `Nexus 4`. Everything is ok. But in some phones, Font size is bigger than i set. For example, in `Samsung A5 2016`, Font sized is 3 times bigger than `Nexus 4`.

```
Nexus 4 screen: 768 x 1280 pixels, 5:3 ratio (~318 ppi density)

A5 screen: 1080 x 1920 pixels, 16:9 ratio (~424 ppi density)
```

As I know, When a phone has better resolution, Everything goes smaller not bigger!

I have just one Layout folder for all resolutions and have two values folders for setting sizes for different resolutions:

```
values-xhdp  : for Nexus 4
```

and

```
values-xxhdp  : for Samsung A5
```

When i decrease font sizes in `values-xxhdp` folder, `Samsung A5` shows fonts in proper size. I set font sizes in `sp` unit.

What I confused is that already I was thinking that in `values-xxhdp` folder I have to increase values because is this for high resolution phone, Not decreasing... What happening? What i should do?

Answer (score 0):

Scaled pixels change according to the user set font size preferences.
Read about screen and [resolution support.](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: In emulator it behaves normally and fonts goes smaller in high  resolution emulator. but in samsung A5 that has higher resolution that Nexus 4, fonts goes very bigger...

Comment: Maybe A5 is set to big font in the settings, and so your sp value is affected by it?

Comment: You should define UI elements in dp as suggested by the link above. And use sp for text size.

Comment: but other apps fonts is normal. just my app fonts goes bigger. but in emulator i see normal behavior. what i have to do?

Answer (score -1):

Give fontSize in sp like 20sp, 30sp, then it will automatically adjust font as per the device.

Comment: i dont understand. in xhdpi i have to set 20sp and in xxhdpi 30sp? this way? as i say, if i set 20sp in both, fonts goes 3 times bigger in samsung A5... if i set 30sp then it goes very bigger... this is my problem... in emulator it goes small but in samsung A5 goes bigger